# Dynamically switch http:listener-config configuration in mule

Tags: mule

I would like to have the ability to switch listener configuration easily  in Mule (CE-3.6.1) from http to https (with basic autentication). I've created a variable in the mule-project.xml 'mule.protocol' and two properties files http.properties and https.properties with some data like port (the same port in http and https), host, password, etc.

in config.xml I have:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${mule.protocol}.properties" />

 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="${host}" port="${port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="${protocol}">    
    <tls:context>
        <tls:key-store type="${keystore.type}" path="${keystore.path}"  keyPassword="${keystore.keyPassword}" password="${keystore.password}" />
    </tls:context>         
</http:listener-config>
```

but I have two problems. 
First, I get a message: Value '${protocol}' is not man-valid with respect to enumeration '[HTTP, HTTPS]'
and the second, section 'tls:context' is permitted only in https case, so I would have to hide it dynamically. How to solve these problems or whether there is another way to easily switch between the configuration of http and https? I'm using HTTP_Listener_Configuration in many services.

Comment: ${protocol} might be a reserved word. Anyways as per ur code, u should use ${mule.protocol} instead of {protocol}. isnt it ?

Comment: By the way,you can enable both endpoints by using <composite-source>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this was only added for Mule 3.8.0 (coming soon). In older versions the protocol attribute does not support properties. You could use a Spring profile as a workaround. You can find more data in the JIRA [ticket](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8936) for this.